# Google Auth + Passport + React-Redux. Once user is authenticated in the back, how can I pass the authenticated user to Redux in the front?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

I'm working with React v16 and redux, on the authentication part of a website. I'm using passport and bcrypt to handle my users password (with a middleware in the Model file), encrypt them and save them to my MongoDB database.

To summarise,  in the back end I have a route that a route {router.get('/auth/google')} that triggers my passport strategy. And this passport strategy should return a user object.
I want to pass this user object to my front end to save it in my redux state. How can I do this?
I've tried with local storage  ( 'localStorage.setItem('user', currentUser)' )  but it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

In the back end:
Passport.js

```
//GOOGLE STRATEGY---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //  This google strategy works both for authentication and login in 
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = googleConfig.postman.client_id
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = googleConfig.postman.client_secret

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback", //if success?
      
  },
// cb = callback

async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile,  cb, done) {
    console.log("profile", profile);
    
    try {
      const currentUser = await MemberModel.findOne({
        googleId: profile.id,
      });
      // In case database doesn't find the user, we must create a new one:
     if(!currentUser){
       const newUser = await new MemberModel({
         googleId:profile.id,
         userName:profile.name.familyName,
         email: profile.email,
         password:null
       }).save();
       if(newUser){        
          done(null,newUser);
   // My solution. save user in local storage
     localStorage.setItem('user', newUser)
       }
     }
      //If the user existed, we are just loggin in:
      done(null, currentUser);
// My solution. save user in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('user', currentUser)

    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }
  }
));

module.exports = passport;
```

googleAuth.js

```
router.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));


router.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/', session:false }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000");
  }
);
```

membersModel.js

```
(...)
/* Google authentication doesn't create a password, and instead it returns password =null or undefined. */
memberSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        if(!this.password===null|| this.password===undefined){
            this.password = contrasenya
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
            hashpassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)

        }
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        hashpassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)
        
        this.password = hashpassword
        next()
    }
    catch (error) {
       
        next(error)
    }
})

memberSchema.post('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        console.log("userSchema.post done");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})


//We set the export to a variable ‘city’ which was defined as 'Schema' on line6, and we exported as a mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('members', memberSchema)
```

FRONT files:

the button component

```
import 'authGoogleAction' from  './actions/loginActions'
const GoogleAuthButton = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const loggedIn = useSelector(state => state.members.loggedIn);   

 
   const singInButton  = ()=> {
       return(
            <button type="button" onClick={authGoogleAction}  className="google-button">
               "Sign In"
            </button>
        )
    }
         
    return(            
        <div>
                     
            <div>{singInButton()}</div>
            <p>User status logged in: {loggedIn? "You are connected":"You are  NOT connected"}</p>
            </div>
    )  
    }

export {GoogleAuthButton}
```

loginActions

```
(...)
export function authGoogleAction() {
    dispatch(
      type: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS',
      payload: localStorage.get('user'),
    }))
      }
```